# Test NodeJS socket.io with custom headers

Tags: node.js, sockets, testing, cookies, socket.io

I'm trying to write simple test to test my NodeJS socket.io app. Problem is that on handshake phase I do require certain values to be there (two cookies and headers). This is what I now do have:

```
var options = {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        'force new connection': true,
        headers: {'accept-langauge': 'foo'}
};

it("send data", function(done) {
   var client = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', options);

   client.once("connect", function(s) {
       expect(s.handshake).to.not.be(undefined);
       expect(s.handshake.headers).to.be.an('object');
       expect(s.handshake.headers['accept-language']).to.be('en');

       client.once("send_premise_to_snet", function(id) {
           id.should.equal("123");

           client.disconnect();
           done();
       });

       client.emit("send_data", 123);
   });
});
```

I would like to be able to set accept-language and cookies so that they would appear in handshake and thus would be accessible through handshake property.

In normal browser request browser would fill headers properly, and now I would like to do it in the test phase as well.

Comment: What's your question? Are you having trouble verifying the handshake headers from the server, or are you asking how to send the correct headers from the server?

Comment: Question is - how to pass headers when doing "client = io.connect". That way they I should be able to read them from handshake data. Note that io.connect is done in nodejs unittest case.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful hit with proper Google query words I managed to find out more information. It seems that currently it is impossible to do with current socket.io and socket.io-client implementations.

There exists few alternative approaches taken but none of them have managed to get through to actual packages.

For further information:

https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/2036

https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/issues/648